# Show similar triangles on unit circle when proving the derivative of $\sin\theta$ geometrically

Tags: geometry

3blue1brown attempts to prove the derivative of $\sin(\theta)$ using geometry at minute 16 of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ

[image: https://i.snag.gy/Tjc3av.jpg]

He says that these two triangles are similar. How do you show that?

Answer (score 1):

When $d\theta$ is sufficiently small, they assume the hypotenuse of the smaller triangle is given by the yellow tangent line to the point on the circle. Since the yellow line is tangent to the circle, then it is also perpendicular to the radial line segment. Now by basic trigonometry, you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

How one shows that:

Since tangent line $\overline{AB}$ is perpendicular to radius $\overline{OA}$ (as Jacky said), $\angle OAB$ is a right angle. Therefore, the elevation of the tangent line from horizontal $\angle CAB$ equals the angle $\angle OAD$ the radius makes with the vertical. Call this angle $\phi := \angle OAB = \angle OAD$.

Since the interior angles of a (flat Euclidean) triangle must sum to $\pi$, and the triangles both have one right angle with the horizontal, and the other angle is $\phi$, the third angle must also match, so $\angle CBA = \theta = \pi - \big(\dfrac{\pi}{2} + \phi \big)$.

[image: Diagram of similar triangles]

Hope that helps.